# How to create Static Dropdownlist values in MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, enums, dropdownlistfor

How can I prepare a model for Dropdownlist static values (not retrieved from database) like enum or list in MVC Model so that it could be used many times in a project? I would appreciate if you can give a good article? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution by describing the parameters as hidden input. I am not sure if there is a more elegant method in order to pass the parameters from View to Controller. Thank you so much for your good sample. I also marked as helpful all of your replies. Here is my final code for those who might encounter a similar problem:

**ApplicantViewModel:**

```
public class ApplicantViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }

    //Codes for Dropdownlist values
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "pdf", Text = "Pdf" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "excel", Text = "Excel" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "word", Text = "Word" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicantController:**

```
public ViewResult Reporting()
{
    var model = new ApplicantViewModel(); 
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult RenderReport(string SelectedValue, string name, string fileName, string dataSource, string table, string filter)
{
    //Codes for rendering report
    ...
}
```

**Reporting.cshtml:**

```
@model MyProject.Models.ApplicantViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("RenderReport", "Applicant", FormMethod.Post,
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
 <div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.Values, "-- select an option --")

    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Report1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="image rapor"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="dataSource" value="ApplicantDataset"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="ApplicantsView"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="David"/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
 </div>  
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As always you could start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

For enums you could use some of the many posts out there illustrating custom helpers. Here's one blog post illustrating such helper: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try it and inform you about the result. I just wondered; 1)If I use these values with a Student entity, I will also add this entity to the same ViewModel. Is that true? 2)If I use two dropdownlist on the same razor having the same values above (for example Yes/No values), in that case do I need to create another SelectListItem? Or can it also be used for different Dropdownlist on the same Razor page? –

Comment: I tested this good approach. But the problem is that: I cannot pass SelectedValue to controller. How can I do this with this methods?

Comment: Your HttpPost controller action could take the view model as parameter and then you will get the selected value in the `SelectedValue` property automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought the same thing and tried yesterday. But although I could pass the viewModel properly, the values except from "Values" are null (Applicants entity and SelectedValue in ViewModel). I know it is strange but I am not sure where may the mistake. Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Import:  using System.Web.Mvc;